# I want to verify a value using text input from an array, but I am not getting an output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, if-statement, textinput

I want to input a value, which will be compared to my dummy data, and once the value is compared,  i'll get an alert if the value is matched or not

//UPDATE - I have made some changes to the code, not the alert is working, but the values are not being matched. only getting the second alert - Error.

```
import { View, Text, FlatList, TextInput, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Button } from 'react-native'
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { CATEGORIES } from '../DummyData/dummy-data'

const renderGridItem = (itemData) =>{
    return (
        <View style={{marginVertical:5,marginVertical:15, flex:1, margin:15}}>
            <Text style={{color:'black'}}>
                {itemData.item.id}
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
}

const Meals = props => {
  const [text, onChangeText] = useState();
  
  var onClick = () => {
        if (renderGridItem === text){
            alert("ID Matched");
        }
        else{
            alert('Error')
            
        }
}
console.log(text)

  return (
      <View>

    <FlatList keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id} 
    data={CATEGORIES} 
    numColumns={2} 
    renderItem={renderGridItem} />

    <TextInput 
    style={styles.tip}
    placeholder='Enter CNIC'
    keyboardType='default'
    onChangeText={onChangeText}
    value={text}
    />

    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.top}  onPress={() => { ()=>onChangeText(text); onClick()} }>
        <Text style={{textAlign:'center'}}>
            Enter 
        </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>



    
    

    </View>

  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    tip:{
        borderWidth:1,
        marginVertical:50, 
        borderRadius:8
    },

    top:{
        width:'30%',
        borderWidth:1,
        marginLeft:140, 
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius:8

    },
   
})

export default Meals
```

//Dummy-Data (Array)

```
import Data from "../Model/Data";

export const CATEGORIES = [
  new Data('c1', 'Person 1', '#f5428d'),

  new Data('c3', 'Person 2', '#f5a442'),

];
```

//Data

```
class Data {
    constructor(id, title){
        this.id=id,
        this.title=title
    }
}

export default Data
```

Comment: In onClick method you need to compare with **text** not **onChangeText** please check it its work or not.

Comment: not working. i can't seem to get the onclick funtion to work. dont know if ive written it correctly

Comment: change onPress **onPress={()=>onClick}**  to  **onPress={()=>onClick()}**

Comment: the button is working, but the id id not matchig

Comment: you need to pass itemData into button onClick() you noting pass to button that's why itemData.item.id getting undefined so conditions not match.

Comment: how can pass the itemdata?

Comment: you can pass from onClick method or you can use loop to get the array text and compare with user-enter text. and in onClick you are compare with the id and text so that conditions is also wrong.

Comment: can you please share the code?

Comment: You want to match value from QR code to your dummy data right?

Comment: no, from the textinput, i have updated the code, do take a look. //added the qr code by mistake

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code it might be helpful to you.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import {
      StyleSheet,
      SafeAreaView,
      TextInput,
      View,
      Text,
      Button,
      TouchableOpacity,
    } from "react-native";
    

const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  function onPressButton() {
    var result = DATA.some((item, index) => item.title == text);
    if (result == true) {
      alert("DATA Found");
    } else {
      alert("DATA not found");
    }
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <TextInput
          style={{ borderBottomWidth: 1, width: "90%", padding: 10 }}
          placeholder="Enter Title"
          onChangeText={(text) => setText(text)}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            width: 100,
            height: 50,
            borderWidth: 1,
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            borderRadius: 10,
            marginTop: 20,
          }}
          onPress={onPressButton}
        >
          <Text>Find</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const DATA = [
  { id: 1, title: "ABC" },
  { id: 2, title: "XYZ" },
];

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
});

export default App;
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: this isn't wrong, but I want to share the data from a different screen. like how I've mentioned in the code above

Comment: got it. used your code for help. thanks!